# Create Array from values of Array within Object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift

`finalRestaurantArray` is an array of `PFObjects` which contains the array `CloseHours` for each object. `CloseHours` contains the closing time for each day of the week [0-6].

**How can I create an array that contains the value of `CloseHours[dayOfWeek]` for each object.** If it is Tuesday (`let dayOfWeek = 1`) the array should look like:

```
 [0015, 2350]
```

#### Current Attempt:

```
    //create array of CloseHours
    let initialCloseRestaurantHours = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("CloseHours") as [String] }
    //get the close hour for given day
    let closeRestaurantHours = initialCloseRestaurantHours.map { $0.objectAtIndex(dayOfWeek) as String }
    //Error: [string] does not have a member named objectAtIndex
```

#### Additional Info

This is the array of Objects `finalRestaurantArray`

```
[<Restaurant: 0x17411aca0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "First One";
    CloseHours =     (
        0005,
        0015,
        0025,
        0035,
        0045,
        0055,
        0065
    );
}, <Restaurant: 0x17411b480, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Second One";
    CloseHours =     (
        0015,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350
    );
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$0.objectAtIndex(dayOfWeek)` try `$0[dayOfWeek]`. `$0` is now a Swift array of type `[String]` and Swift arrays do not have the `objectAnIndex:` method.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. and thanks for the heads up. now i'm assuming this isn't the ideal way to accomplish what i'm trying to do?

Comment: If your goal is to get an array of close times per day then it works well. The only thing that was slightly confusing was that `initialCloseRestaurantHours` was an array of arrays. Perhaps naming it `closeRestaurantHoursArrays` or maybe adding a comment that its an array of string arrays might be useful?